# I would like to create a redirection rule to redirect site request e.g. http://www.company.com or http://web.company.com to https://secure.company.com

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I would like to create a redirection rule to redirect site request e.g. http://www.company.com or http://web.company.com to https://secure.company.com

I am using iis 7 with the url rewrite module installed. I had try to find some hints but no avail

Comment: When you have difficulty writing a single rule, use multiple rules please.

Comment: I don't know how